# Existence of a Pivot Point in Euclidean Geometry

Tags: geometry

In geometry there is a term called a pivot point. There exists a pivot point 'P' in the interior of a convex polyhedron in a euclidean space if and only if every single line through 'P' contains exactly zero or two vertices of the polyhedron.

I asked one of my professors, but he gave me a very narrow example of a cube, but I want to know the maximum number of pivot points that exist in a polyhedron. Can someone please help me prove how many exist?

Comment: Did you make an effort to solve this problem before posting it? Do you have at least a conjecture about the solution?

Comment: Also asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/186882/12357

Comment: Also asked at http://mathoverflow.net/q/186882/12357 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/186988/12357

Comment: This question is from the USAMTS 2014-2015 Round Two problem set ([problem 4](http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_2.pdf)). This round ends on 8 Dec 2014, and this question will remain locked until after this date.

Comment: Thinly disguised question from the current USAMTS Round Two problem set ([problem 4](http://usamts.org/Tests/Problems_26_2.pdf)). This question will remain locked until after the submission deadline of 8 Dec 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $P$ has two pivot points $x$ and $y$. Pick a vertex $v_1$ of $P$ not on the line $xy$. Then the line $v_1x$ goes through a vertex $v_2$ of $P$. The line $v_2y$ goes through a vertex $v_3$ of $P$, the line $v_3x$ goes through $v_4$, etc. Eventually, this process must repeat, yielding a list of vertices $v_1,v_2, \dots, v_n$ of $P$. By construction, these vertices must all be coplanar, along with $x$ and $y$. Furthermore, since $P$ is convex, they form a convex polygon with pivots $x$ and $y$. Therefore, it is sufficient to show that no convex polygon can have more than one pivot.

For a convex polygon, we have that there is only one way to pair up the vertices for the pivot, because there must be an equal number of vertices on each side of $v_iv_j$ if $v_iv_j$ is to go through the pivot. This forces a unique pairing (if one exists), and at most one pivot.

Therefore a polyhedron can have at most one pivot.

Comment: Can you please give an example of this. I'm finding it hard to visualize it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. An example of what?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  a sphere is in many ways a polyhedron with an infinite number of faces.